# identifying non isomorphic graphs with no comparison graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

hi one of my homework problems is "Draw all nonisomorphic simple graphs with four vertices" my issue with this is that I thought isomorphism was used as a comparison, so how would you start to draw a graph that is non isomorphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means, draw a representative of all possible isomorphism classes. For instance if it was two vertices instead of four, you only have the graphs

$$V=\{0,1\}, E=\emptyset$$
and
$$V=\{0,1\}, E=\{(0,1)\}$$

as any other simple graph on two vertices will be isomorphic to one of these two.

---

To perhaps demistify the wording of the problem a little. The question is asking you the following.

> Draw 11 simple graphs with four vertices so that no two graphs are isomorphic to each other.

Above, I have shown all 2 simple graphs with two vertices such that no two graphs are isomorphic to each other, now you should try to do it with four vertices.

Comment: Ok so I'm trying to wrap my head around this but, to my understanding for a graph to be isomorphic it has to have a 1:1 and onto function with its isomorphism. What makes the 11 possibilities(for a simple graph of 4 vertices) NON isomorphic? I hope my question is clear

Comment: There is no such thing as 'a graph is isomorphic'. Isomorphism is a comparison between **two different graphs**. Either graph 1 is isomorphic to graph 2, or graph 1 is not isomorphic to graph 2.

Comment: Right, so the original question was to draw all non isomorphic graphs with 4 vertices. So would I draw all possible graphs of 4 vertices and compare them all to each other in order to eliminate the isomorphic ones?

Comment: I've edited my answer to hopefully help. You should draw 11 graphs and then prove (or at least convince yourself) that no two graphs in that set of 11 graphs are isomorphic to each other. That is, if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic to each other, then you have made a mistake.

Comment: OH OK, yes that rewording certainly makes the answers a lot clearer. Thank you. Just to make sure I have this correct, I'm looking at the answers and you need to preserve # of edges. So in general you should draw graphs with increasing amounts of edges

Comment: There are graphs on four vertices that have the same number of edges but are not isomorphic, so edge number is only a necessary condition for isomorphism, not sufficient.(Example: $E=\{(0,1), (2,3)\}, E' = \{(0,1),(1,2)\}$ are not isomorphic but both have two edges)

Answer (score 4):

You don’t draw ‘a graph that is non-isomorphic’; that is a meaningless expression for the reason that you gave, namely, that isomorphism is a property of pairs of graphs. You draw a simple graph with four vertices. Then you find another simple graph with four vertices that is not isomorphic to the first graph. Then you try to find a third simple graph with four vertices that is not isomorphic to either of the first two. And you keep going until you reach the point at which every possible simple graph with four vertices is isomorphic to one of the graphs that you’ve already drawn.

Comment: Great! I'm starting to get it

Answer (score 0):

The question asks to draw all possible simple graphs on $4$ vertices such that no two of the graphs drawn are isomorphic.

The complete graph $K_4$ has $6$ edges, and it is possible to either choose or not choose each edge.  The choices made for each of these edges gives a particular (labeled) graph on $4$ vertices.  The path graph consisting of edge set $\{12, 23, 34\}$ and the path graph consisting of edge set $\{23, 34, 41\}$ are different as labeled graphs but are isomorphic (ie are in the same isomorphism class). More generally, if $V=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $V^{\{2\}}$ is the set of all $2$-subsets of $V$, then $|V^{\{2\}}| = {n \choose 2}$, and the set of $2^{n \choose 2}$ subsets of $V^{\{2\}}$ corresponds to the set of all $2^{n \choose 2}$ labeled graphs on $n$ vertices.  This set can be partitioned into isomorphism classes, ie the partition is such that two labeled graphs are in the same part if and only if they are isomorphic.

The set of $2^{4 \choose 2} = 2^6 = 64$ different labeled graphs on $4$ vertices can be partitioned into isomorphism classes, and the question asks to draw one graph from each isomorphism class.

To answer your question, ignore labelings on vertices, and first draw all graphs on $4$ vertices containing exactly $0$ edges (there is only one such graph), then all graphs containing exactly $1$ edge (there is only one such graph), all graphs containing exactly $2$ edges (there are 2 such graphs, because the two edges can be incident or independent), etc. And you get that the total number of pairwise nonisomorphic graphs on $4$ vertices is $1+1+2+3+2+1+1 = 11$.